# Как организовать передачу аудио-данных по сети в реальном времени

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c++builder

Мне нужно с компьютера А передать звук по сети компьютеру B.

1. Каким образом я смогу на компьютере B проверить правильную доставку аудиоданных и желательно воспроизвести то, что я прислал?
2. Как вообще оформляется аудио для передачи в среде *ethernet*? Я имею в виду протоколы - какой именно протокол - то есть, протокол прикладного уровня, или используется протокол транспортного уровня (*UDP*)?

Просто есть приложение, которое передает c одного компьютера на другой текстовые данные по *Ethernet*. Но это текст, а мне нужен звук.

Может, кто-нибудь посоветует какие-нибудь исходники программ по этой теме? Ссылки на книги, ресурсы и т.д.

**Обновление**

Хорошо, звук - это просто набор байтов, которые я могу передавать по сети. Тогда я могу использовать только транспортный уровень для передачи - например UDP + этот набор байтов , то есть звук? И протокол типа RTP можно не использовать.

Но ведь нужно наверно отличить этот набор байтов (звук) от набора байтов (просто текст). Какая-то еще информация должна передаваться в сообщении по сети, чтобы программа на другой стороне поняла, что это именно звук.
И как мне это воспроизвести - какая-нибудь программа должна быть, чтобы проверить правильность доставки данных.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вы хотите, чтобы воспроизводилось в режиме реального времени (как Skype), или как аудио файл?

Comment: реал конечно :)

Comment: Моя задача - передавать голосовую информацию - то есть речь в режим реального времени.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Есть готовые решения. IceCast погуглите.

Answer (score 3):

Звук ничем не отличается от других видов информации, это просто байтики, сети вообще фиолетово что именно она транспортирует.

Если у вас на входе есть звуковой поток (wav или как-то кодированный), то в самой наивной имплементации вы можете просто этот же поток передавать по сети.

Для начала советую протокол TCP - он берет на себя большинство трудностей типа гарантии доставки и поддержания соединения.

Comment: Хорошо, звук - это просто набор байтов, которые я могу передавать по сети.

Comment: Автор вопроса не владеет теоретическими основами, а просто сыплет словами, вроде "Ethernet", "протоколы", "транспортный" и пр., по сути не понимая их значений. Поэтому попытки формальных объяснений в данном случае, не приведут, увы, ни к чему. Автору следует разобраться в теории для начала.

Answer (score 3):

1. используя WaveForm API вы можете осуществлять захват с аудиоисточника и воспроизводить из буфера.
2. это просто набор данных. Чаще всего используется протокол UDP без подтверждения датаграмм, ибо потери нескольких пакетов в речевом сообщении не так критичны, тут главное время доставки, что в случае TCP несравненно дольше. В то же время, есть промежуточный по свойствам RDP и RUDP, имеют подтверждение дейтаграмм.

> Может, кто-нибудь посоветует какие-нибудь исходники программ по этой
>   теме? Ссылки на книги, ресурсы и т.д.

- более подробно рекомендую ознакомиться - А. Уколов. Прототип VoIP телефона. - ПРОграммист, 2010, №3 http://raxp.radioliga.com/cnt/s.php?p=pro3.pdf. Это конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос в цитате.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно под реалтаймом понимается передача условно бесконечного файла, иначе говоря файла окончание которого заранее не изветстено. Хотя возможны варианты когда в реалтайме передается конкретный файл размер которого заранее известен в том числе и клиенту. При этом обычно в качетсве траснпортного уровня используют UDP. Хоть UDP не гарантирует доставку пакетов (но целостность доставленых проверяет!) и порядок их получения, используют именно его из-за высокой производительности. Более того, протоколы бычно проектируются именно под UDP.

Так как клиент должен воспроизводить поток в реальном времени, нужно передавать ему данные отдельными порциями которые называются фреймы. Фрейм - это блок данных достаточный для декодирования и воспроизведения. Дело в том, что на практике применяются всевозможные алгоритмы сжатия потока, кодеки спроектированы так что принимают фреймы.

Далее фреймы делятся на пакеты, под этими пакетами понимаются уже IP-пакеты. Тут опят возможны варианты, например фреймы могут состоять из одного пакета, а могут из нескольких - зависит от задачи.

Пакеты обычно содержат номер фрейма и свой номер внутри этого фрейма или пакеты нумеруются глобальным счетчиком. Пакеты могут иметь признак конца фрейма. С помощью этих счетчиков, флажков и т.д. и выполняется контроль целостности и порядок приема.

Особо хочу отметить что сопособ разделения на пакеты имеет большое значение. Например было бы ошибкой передавать в одном каком-то пакете метаданные обо всем фрейме, потому как при потере такого пакета теряется по сути и весь фрейм.

Обязательно рекомендую вам к ознакомлению протокол [RTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP).